# CSS style a:visited not being honored

Tags: html, css

Anyone know why my followed link color of grey is not being honored by Safari?  Works on Chrome.

```
<style type="text/css">
a:link {
    color:#6495ED;
}
a:visited {
    color : grey; 
} 
a:active,
a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Try changing it to `color:gray !important`.

Comment: Just a callout, `hex` values offer MUCH more flexibility. The code would be `#CCC` instead of `grey`.

Comment: @Mordred Using !important for something like this is a *terrible* idea. `!important` should be avoided as much as possible in order to avoid specificity wars in the code.

Comment: Tried changing to gray, to #CCC and to #808080 but no dice.  Could it be because I also have this line of code later on? <body text="#A8A8A8">

Comment: @PatrikAlienus I wasn't saying it was a smart idea, but if some CSS somewhere else was specifying the a:visited color, it would at least let him see if that was the case.

Comment: Wasn't a CSS problem after all.  I had double forward slashes in my link addresses:

    ./12345678_ROTCH_20140127_123640//12345678_ROTCH_20140127_123640.htm

This resulted in the variable browser interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it is `gray` in the HTML color names instead of `grey`

`Grey` is British English, but spelling in coding is always (as far as I've seen) American English.

Answer (score 0):

Just a callout, `hex` values offer **MUCH** more flexibility.

The code would be `#808080` instead of `grey` (or as you've done, `gray`).

**Play with `Hex Values` here:**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names

Comment: Please do not link to w3schools, as it is not an accurate resource for HTML, or any other programming language for that matter. Please see: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Sure, I have alternatives. One sec.